# Make i18n channels on chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, languages, internationalization

Now I can only talk about languages, but I use many languages. I know English a little bit, but I'm not good at it. Please make language or country channels on chat (you can get the country from the profile or make it clickable). This would allow for non-native speakers to talk to somebody and ask how to write better questions.

Many questions are bad because people don't know English.

Comment: I think there already are: I'm positive I've seen a persian and russian chat room on Chat.SO.

Comment: but they will get closed soon, mods did not see them yet. chatting is not for everybody.

Comment: I think Stackoverflow is a great site and would be even better if a site like this would be available in other languages. The problem is promoting them. My Japanese friends (CS students), for example, they have never heard about Stackoverflow.com!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing about the FAQ about it. Just because there are many per-progamming-language rooms, it doesn't mean there must only be per-programming-language rooms. I'm not so sure that speaking more in your language will help your English, however.

Please note:

- The [Poland room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/481) has only had 2 messages (one of which in English!); remember that rooms with less than 15 messages are considered not worth keeping (thus they won't be frozen after sufficient idle time, but deleted and made invisible to users without 10k rep).
- The [Persian room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/418/persian) has only just enough activity to keep itself open, but hardly any critical mass to have some real chatting action going on.

Answer (score 4):

You could start a room (you have enough reputation here on MSO for example) that advertises itself as "chat about X in language Y" - or even miss out the "about X" bit!

You could then provide a link to this room in your profile and anywhere else you think people would see it (Twitter, Facebook etc.). Anyone interested would be free to join and chat in the specified language. The menus and options would still be in English though.

There are already some rooms on [chat.so](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/):

- [Polish](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/481/poland)
- [Persian](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/418/persian)

As @Pekka points out in the comments, if there is enough activity in the room it will remain open.

Comment: Polish is my channel, so it does not count. plus it will get closed when mods see it, trust me on that. Please close the other one to, be fair!

Comment: @01 - I didn't check the ownership ;) Also why do you think they'll close it?

Comment: why they close anything? they have the reasons! its not about any programming language for starters(I bet its in the FAQ), but after they close it I will make one about java. when you have the hammer everybody look like nails.

Comment: @01 please show an example of a chat room with some level of activity that got "closed by mods". You are aware that rooms that lack activity will get closed automatically?

Comment: `when you have the hammer everybody look like nails` LOL

Comment: @01 I've created some channels, none of them were closed arbitrarily. As @Pekka mentions the channels get auto-frozen if there as been no activity for 14 days. Activity, means messages being posted regularly by atleast 2 people, not including Feeds.