# What languages can I use on the chat/ Q&A sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, languages, non-english-speakers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is English required on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow)
>   [What languages are allowed to speak in SE chat rooms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136259/what-languages-are-allowed-to-speak-in-se-chat-rooms)

Some time ago, I had a issue and asked for a solution at Stackoverflow.

Now - one of the people was from my country, Israel. Once he found I'm from Israel too he started writing comments in Hebrew, and surprisingly - they were **fine!** I was sure that Stack Exchange allows only English.

I told him that we'll better move the discussion to chat and delete these comments. He agreed. We spoke Hebrew on the chat, everything was fine.

but **is it legal?** I'm not sure we're allowed to speak different languages on Stack Exchange.

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> ### For the chat
>
> The short answer is: *whatever language the other folks present in the room are comfortable speaking.*
>
> All else being equal, if you jump into a room and start posting stuff that isn't understandable to the majority of the users there, you're probably going to get some pushback. And as a practical matter, if those moderating the room (moderators, owners, 10k users) can't understand what you're saying, it stands a good chance of being deleted.
>
> #### Long answer: chat is not a venue for private discussion, and most of these sites are dedicated to English-speaking content
>
> There is no [private messaging feature available to Stack Exchange users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user). Therefore, using a language that only you and one other person in a room understand is actually *a bad thing* purely based on the rules of the site. (Read the linked discussion for all the reasons for *why* that rule is in place)
>
> But beyond that, the sites themselves are dedicated to English-language content, and Chat exists primarily to support them. With the exception of chat rooms associated with specific, [non-English language sites](https://german.stackexchange.com/), the majority of content in Chat should also be in English. I could see making exceptions to this in a few (specific and hopefully rare) scenarios, but by and large we're not set up to support moderating conversations in languages that the moderators, the SE staff, and the majority of users on the site do not understand. When there's any doubt as to the appropriateness of a conversation (for instance: it gets flagged) and it can't be understood, it should be deleted.

Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136282/178505

### For Q&A sites

Most sites are allowed to speak in English Only. Because it is accepted language for conversation on SE. But there are some exceptions like https://german.stackexchange.com/ which supports German.

Comment: Good answer, but #1 - it's not your answer, even if you have included a link to source. #2 - what about the Q&A? This answer covers only the chat.

Comment: Oh, now it's a nice answer. Let me just make titles.

Comment: I am not getting why I am getting downvote. As I have clearly mentioned. From where this source is.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you shouldn't answer an exact duplicate with a quote from the previous answer to the duplicated question.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk I understand, although I've accepted your answer. You had to **only reference to the answer**, not copy it.

Comment: If I was eligible to close answer I have voted for closing question. @Danielδ And given source copy

Comment: You can flag it as a duplicate then.  And @NadavS. that's true for a comment, but if you know about an exact duplicate, you shouldn't answer, you should at most comment.  Simply flag/vote to close.