# Is it acceptable to use chat in other language?

Tags: discussion, chat, languages

I just found [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14140855#14140855) where people talk in [Gujarati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarati_language) language (but using the English alphabets*).

It is acceptable? I am asking because AFAIK anyone can read chat rooms (if (s)he does not have permission to chat).

Also, they talk about some [programming issues](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14142783#14142783) as well as some [personal matters](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14140855#14140855).

---

<sup>* I am talking for this room only. Actual Gujarati Language has it's own [alphabets/script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarati_alphabet)). So don't try to translate! :-)</sup>

Comment: The only issue I see is if someone is flagworthy there is unlikely to be anyone able to deal with it. I think the general consensus is "if the room is primarily for discussion of content in the parent site" it is fine, regardless of language.

Comment: I don't understand the significance of the *English alphabet* (well, *Latin alphabet*) here.

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92996/policy-is-it-ok-to-have-dedicated-foreign-language-chat-rooms